# Sprite scaled and distorted after loading - Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm quite new to three.js, building 3d globe with satellite sprite moving around it.

[image]

The problem is - sprite image gets distorted after loading - aspect ratio is ignored and initial scale is about 5x of its size. I'm downscaling manually but the image gets distorted as I pick numbers manually for each axis e.g. `satelliteSprite.scale.set(0.14, 0.075, 1);`

My satellite image: [image]

**I have 2 questions here:**

1. How do I load it correctly so at least aspect ratio will be
   respected?
2. When I add `AxesHelper` to the sprite why its not aligned to the image plane?

original `<img>` vs downscaled sprite `(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)`:
[image]

my code for satellite, earth, camera here:

```js
//.........SPRITE
var satelliteTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/img/sections/section-astronaut/small-satellite.png');
var satelliteSprite = new THREE.Sprite(new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: satelliteTexture,
  color: 0xffffff,
  fog: false
}));
satelliteSprite.scale.set(0.14, 0.075, 1);
satelliteSprite.position.setFromSpherical(new THREE.Spherical().set(0.565, Math.PI * 2 - 0.9, Math.PI * 2 + 0.5));
earth.add(satelliteSprite);
window['satelliteSprite'] = satelliteSprite;

var axesHelperSatelliteSprite = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
satelliteSprite.add(axesHelperSatelliteSprite);

//..........CAMERA
var camera = window['camera'] = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.01, 100);
camera.position.z = 1.5;

//..........EARTH
var earth = window['earth'] = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(earthRadius, earthSegments, earthSegments),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/img/sections/section-astronaut/2_no_clouds_4k.jpg'),
    bumpMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/img/sections/section-astronaut/elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
    bumpScale: 0.002,
    specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/img/sections/section-astronaut/water_4k.png'),
    specular: new THREE.Color(0x111111),
    wireframe: false
  })
);
earth.rotation.x = 0.4;
earth.rotation.y = -1.95;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create **square** png texture with transparency so it will not get stretched/distorted and now you can scale equally for each axis e.g. `satelliteSprite.scale.set(0.08, 0.08, 0.08)`

2) set filters and anisotropy for the texture

```
  satelliteTexture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();       
  satelliteTexture.minFilter = satelliteTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  satelliteTexture.minFilter = satelliteTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
```